# If I render text that includes HTML tags in my React app, is there a way to display the HTML?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm building a website for someone else right now. It's a dynamic website (built with React) with content that is fetched from a database. The website owner can then log-in and update the content  without having to contact me for it.

Right now, the code where the content is displayed looks likes this:

```
<p className={classes.paragraph} key={index}>
   {paragraph}
</p>
```

If my client decides to update his content with some HTML tags, the processed HTML is not being displayed. I guess this is a good thing because someone with malicious intentions could use a script tag to do stuff behind the scenes. However, the only one who is touching the content is my client, and i want him to be able to use basic HTML in order to create bold or italic text and stuff like that. Is there a way to make this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Answer (score 1):

Option is to put `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'some html content here'}}` on a html tag.

Example:

```
<div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: '<span><i>Some</i> html text inside</span>',
    }}
/>
```

or in your case:

```
<p 
    className={classes.paragraph}
    key={index}
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: paragraph,
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.